# Word 2010 Fill In field

Tags: ms-office, word-2010

Im creating a cover letter that prompts for a Business Name and Title. The Business Name will be used multiple times in the letter. Currently I'm using:

```
{ FILLIN "Business Name" \d "Business" \* MERGEFORMAT }
```

This fill in field is used about 5 times. When the template is opened, it prompts for the Business Name 5 times. Instead of entering it in 5 times, is it possible to prompt one time and use it in the other 4 areas?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you would be able to use an ASK field instead, and use e.g.

```
{ ASK bmname "the question" }
```

to get the value and

```
{ REF bmname }
```

or just

```
{ bmname }
```

to insert each copy of the result.
But AFAICR Word only prompts automatically with FILLIN, which means that it can be easier to use the nested field

```
{ SET bmname { FILLIN "the question" } }
```

to get the value and

```
{ REF bmname }
```

or

```
{ bmname }
```

to insert each copy of the answer. (All the {} have to be the special field code braces that you can insert using ctrl-F9 on Windows Word).